# Using jQuery UI "drag and drop" for pair divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to pair elements with drag and drop. The matching method is the hidden text inside the divs.  The user have to drag the element from the ".answerContainer" and drop it to the correct ".circle" div.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="circleContainer">
    <div class="circle first lineOne"> <span class="question">1</span></div>                   
    <div class="circle second lineOne"><span class="question">2</span></div>
    <div class="circle third lineTwo"> <span class="question">3</span></div>
</div>
<ul class="answerContainer">
     <li class="first">   <span class="answer">1</span></li>
     <li class="second">  <span class="answer">2</span></li>
     <li class="third">   <span class="answer">3</span></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
$( ".answerContainer li" ).draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  containment: "document",
  cursor: "move"
});
$(".circle").each(function(i){
     $this=$(this);
     $this.droppable({
          accept:  function(event, ui) {
                    if($this.text()==event.text()){ 
                        return true;
                    }
                  },
          activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    deleteAnswer( ui.draggable );
                }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Some of your divs have spaces, and some do not, so using `text()` may or may not match. Use `.find('span').text()` instead.
2. You should use `$(this)` instead of `$this` within your accept callback, because $this gets overwritten every time by the `each` command.

So:

```
$(".circle").each(function(i){
     $this=$(this);
     $this.droppable({
          accept:  function(element) {
                    if($(this).find('span').text()==element.find('span').text()) { 
                        return true;
                    }
                  },
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    deleteAnswer( ui.draggable );
                }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ohh, yes, the spaces! Thank you very much!